# How to stop Eclipse from debugging into our library code

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I have two Android projects, one is a library and the other one is the application.
I wrote the library myself and I add this library into my application.
The problem I have right now is when I debug , it keeps going into the library and it is slowing down my debug process tremendously.  Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to preferences/Java/Debug/Step filtering and add your library package to the filters. I've not tried this with the ADK but it works for the JDK.

Comment: I should have added that if you do accidentally step into a method, <F7> will run to the exit of the method